# Conditioinal select using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table **applicant** with a field like this: `id, crew_id, name`. and I have another table

```
`certificates: id, applicant_id, certificate number`.
'documents: id, applicant_id, document_number, expired.
'tests: id, applicant_id, name, score.
```

all I want is to return applicant status, so if there's applicant_id in **certificates** the status will be 'under recruitment', if there's applicant_id in **certificates** and document status will be **'processing'** and if there's applicant_id in **certificates**, **documents** and **tests** table then status will be 'complete'. is it possible to accomplish this just by using select with sub select?

so the result latter will be a record like this: applicant_id: 10500, status: 'complete'. Maybe like IF(select applicant_id from certificates where c.applicant_id = a.id) as status ?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: provide sample data and your expected output in table format

Comment: Or, better, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: 'is it posible to accomplish this just by using select with sub select?'- Yes

Comment: oh i'm really sorry guys, it just too complex for me even for asking. i think i have to use IF. Maybe like IF(select applicant_id from certificates where c.applicant_id = a.id). sorry i'm very confuse.

Comment: IF(select applicant_id from certificates where c.applicant_id = a.id) as status from applicants as a, left join certificates as c where c.applicant_id = a.id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can left join the table `applicant` to the other 3 and use a CASE statement for your conditions:

```
select a.*,
  case 
    when c.applicant_id is not null and d.applicant_id is not null and c.applicant_id is not null then 'complete'
    when c.applicant_id is not null and d.applicant_id is not null then 'processing'
    when c.applicant_id is not null then 'under recruitment'
    else null
  end result
from applicant a
left join certificates c on c.applicant_id = a.id
left join documents d on d.applicant_id = a.id
left join tests t on t.applicant_id = a.id
```

Comment: it give me this error Static analysis:

3 errors were found during analysis.

Unexpected keyword. (near "select" at position 298)
Unexpected end of CASE expression (near " " at position 296)
This type of clause was previously parsed. (near "select" at position 298)

Comment: Where do you try this code? You tagged MySql. This is valid code for any SQL database. See this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6rHU1BK6uo3Pq6sySiD9Vy/0

Comment: i testing it on mysql and using phpmyadmin.

Comment: As you can see in the fiddle link the statement is valid. Copy and paste it as it is.

Comment: thank, seem like it work but it the status only work on complete. the other give blank.

Comment: The result is 'complete' only if the id exists in all 3 tables. The result is null if the id does not exist in any of the tables. Isn't this what you want? I don't have access to your data. If you can prepare a fiddle with sample data then I would see if there is a problem

Comment: if there's applicant_id in certificates and document status will be 'processing' and if there's applicant_id in certificates, documents and tests table then status will be 'complete'. sorry, i suppose to make a fiddle before posting the question.

Comment: This is what the code does. Check the order of the WHEN clauses inside CASE. First condition is the id exists in all 3 tables. If not check for 2 tables. If not checks 1 table.

Comment: yes but even if there's applicant_id on the documents table it still returns blank which suppose it returns 'under processing' or 'under recruitment'?

Comment: In the question you say: " if there's applicant_id in certificates **and** document status will be 'processing'". You did not mention anything if the id is only in documents.

Comment: can you modify your code, the answer that i selected is too complex but it works, if you can make your code working i will choose yours since it simple and easy to understand and maybe you can add distinct by applicant_id?

Comment: My answer works for the requirement that you mention in your question, but I think that you want something else. Post sample data and expected results preferably in a fiddle.

Comment: ah it seem your answer is right and more simple, i found some doesn't have data that why it doesn't showed like what i want. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query

```
select applicant.id, 
case 
when certificates.applicant_id is not null and documents.applicant_id is not null and tests.applicant_id is not null then 'complete'
when certificates.applicant_id is not null and documents.applicant_id is not null and tests.applicant_id is null then 'processing'
when certificates.applicant_id is not null and documents.applicant_id is null and tests.applicant_id is null then 'under recruitment'
else '' end as 'status'
from applicant left join certificates on certificates.applicant_id=applicant.id
left join documents on documents.applicant_id=applicant.id
left join tests on tests.applicant_id=applicant.id
```

Comment: it gives me this error, but i think your code is like what i want to. #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '..applicant_id is not null then 'complete'
when certificates.applicant_id is no' at line 3

Comment: try now @Ying It will work fine now. Changed as two dots were added instead of one

Comment: it runs but seem like only working on complete meanwhile on another applicant id it returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Use Below query:

```
SELECT a.id, 
CASE WHEN c.applicant_id IS NOT NULL AND d.applicant_id IS NOT NULL AND t.applicant_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'completed'
WHEN c.applicant_id IS NOT NULL AND d.applicant_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'processing'
WHEN c.applicant_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'under recruitment'
ELSE 'application id doesn\'t exist' END AS STATUS
FROM applicant a 
LEFT JOIN certificates c ON a.id = c.applicant_id 
LEFT JOIN documents d ON a.id = d.applicant_id
LEFT JOIN tests t ON a.id = t.applicant_id
```

Comment: it suppose return 'under recruitment' or 'under proccess' but it just work on complete status.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sql joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) to accomplish this task.

You can use following methods to check the conditions.

1.under recruitment- **use the query**

```
  SELECT applicant_id 
FROM certificates AS c
 LEFT JOIN documents AS d 
ON c.applicant_id =d.applicant_id
 WHERE d.Key IS NULL;
```

This will return you all the applicant_id s' which belongs only to certificates table.and the data that is generated through this query can be named as **under recruitment**.You can simply use an **if function** to categorize them into under recruitment, processing ,complete statuses.

2.processing-**use the query**

```
  SELECT applicant_id 
FROM certificates AS c 
INNER JOIN documents AS d 
ON c.applicant_id =d.applicant_id ;
```

This query will return you all the applicant_id s' that belongs to both certificates, documents tables.The data that is generated through this query can be named as **processing**

3.complete-**use the query**

```
   SELECT applicant_id  FROM certificates AS c
JOIN documents AS d ON c.applicant_id  = d.applicant_id  
JOIN tests AS t ON c.applicant_id  = t.applicant_id
```

This query will return you all the applicant_id s' that belongs to all the tables.The data that is generated through this query can be named as **complete **

It's not mandotary to use **AS** when you assign the values to a variable that you got from a table.You can use a space without using the keyword AS.

For EX:

```
SELECT applicant_id  FROM certificates AS c
JOIN documents AS d ON c.applicant_id  = d.applicant_id  
JOIN tests AS t ON c.applicant_id  = t.applicant_id

//can be written as

  SELECT applicant_id  FROM certificates c
JOIN documents d ON c.applicant_id  = d.applicant_id  
JOIN tests t ON c.applicant_id  = t.applicant_id
```

You can use these queries and a function in order to fulfill your task.
Hope this was helpful.

Comment: sorry but it's not like what i expected. the other answer is like what i expected but not perfect.